# PinchZoom not working with scaleType:matrix

Tags: android, viewflipper, image-gallery, android-gallery, zooming

Hello I am new to Android.I am working on an application in which I need to flip the images(*like gallery*) and zoom the image in focus.Currently the flipping(*using viewFlipper*) and pinch to Zoom is working fine.

But I want to stop Flipping on last image.

I have used `ViewFlipper.stopFlipping()` and its works fine if I set `scaleType:fitXY` in xml **but pinchZoom does not work with it**.

AND

If I use `ScaleType:matrix` the pinch **zoom works but** on stopping the flipping on last image,it **cuts the last image.**

I have searched alot but haven't got any thing useful.
Any help will highly be appreciated.I have been in this problem from many days.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Zoom extends View {
private Drawable image;
private int zoomControler=20; 
public Zoom(Context context)
{
    super(context);
    image=context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon);
    setFocusable(true);

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDraw(canvas);
image.setBounds((getWidth()/2)-zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)-zoomControler, (getWidth()/2)+zoomControler, (getHeight()/2)+zoomControler);
    image.draw(canvas);
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP)// zoom in
        zoomControler+=10;
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN) // zoom out
        zoomControler-=10;
    if(zoomControler<10)
        zoomControler=10;

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

}